# deploying a scala app built using IDEA

Tags: scala, deployment, intellij-idea, mongodb, casbah

I developed a simple scala app that uses casbah to query the DB for the command line argument passed to it. For example

```
$ querydb.scala execution 10
```

it will run a casbah query to find 10 records matching execution in mongo. Now i have two questions.

1) How do i test this in my local. If i click execute in intellij it is just running the program, i am not able to pass command line arguments to my program.

2) How do i deploy it to run on my server, it is just going to used as console app in my ubuntu server, but im not sure how i should deploy this, which files i should put up on the server and how do i execute it in server, and stuff like that.

Any pointers would be useful for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

or try to use sbt, IDEA has a plugin with sbt, the wiki of it has an explanation on how to use it.
I usually use sbt directly in Terminal instead of running in IDE.

Answer (score 2):

1) First you need to find "Select Run/Debug Configuration" button at the top of your screen

[image]

Click on it and choose edit

[image]

Create new one, if you haven't got it yet.

[image]

Your program parameters should be written in "Program parameters" field

[image]

2) Compile your .scala files with [scalac](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/tools/scalac.html) and you'll got .class files.
Then deploy it, as you [usually do](http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/debuggingtips_Java.html) with `java` code. Hence you don't need to install scala on target machine - all you need is JDK.